# How to print labels using module "printer_zpl2"

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-9, zebra-printers, zpl-ii

I'm using odoo 9  and i want to print products labels using zebra printer that's why i have installed a custom module named "printer_zpl2" but i don't know how to use it to print labels with it . is there anyone who used it before who can help me ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Be sure the printer is connected to your server
2. Go to Settings > Printing > Labels > ZPL II to create a new label (define model and add elements(design + fields ex:"object.default_code" in data field))
3. To call the action to execute the label printer you **MUST** update the module and add the ir.record value(ex for product template, will show you in the "More")

   ```
   <record model="ir.values" id="wizard_wizard_print_product_label">
       <field name="name">Print Product Label</field>
       <field name="key">action</field>
       <field name="key2">client_action_multi</field>
       <field name="model">product.template</field>
       <field name="value" eval="'ir.actions.act_window,' + str(ref('printer_zpl2.action_wizard_print_record_label_view'))"/>
   </record>
   ```
4. Open a product, select More and check for "Print Product Label", select the printer and the label you will use